# Cannot get the NotificationListenerService class to work

Tags: android

I have a android application that is trying to use the new NotificationListenerService class from api 18. I have created my own service class that inherits from this class and overrode the onNotificationPosted and onNotificationRemoved events and although my service seems to start just fine these 2 events never seem to be called when I get or remove a notification.

Has anyone had any success with this class or possibly any source code they are will to share demonstrating exactly how to use this class?

Comment: My 2 cents for anyone facing it in Android Oreo.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57780649/9192635

Comment: Here is my comment with a solution that worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62934667/10652152

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In my experience, almost all of these answers are so damn close to the right solution!

The **CORE** problem seems to happen during development; as you are developing your code the "Notification access" settings stop being honored when you **update** your app between debug sessions.

If your APK/binary changes and your NotificationListenerService stops:

- Rebooting fixes it.
- Going back in to "Notification access" and disabling and re-enabling your app it fixes it.

Hopefully this isn't a problem when updating your app through Google Play.

As a best practice, for my app I add an overflow menu option that only shows up in non-release builds that allows me easy access to the settings:

NotificationListener.java:

```
public class NotificationListener
    extends NotificationListenerService
    implements RemoteController.OnClientUpdateListener
{
    private static final int VERSION_SDK_INT = VERSION.SDK_INT;

    public static boolean supportsNotificationListenerSettings()
    {
        return VERSION_SDK_INT >= 19;
    }

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    @TargetApi(19)
    public static Intent getIntentNotificationListenerSettings()
    {
        final String ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS;
        if (VERSION_SDK_INT >= 22)
        {
            ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS = Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS;
        }
        else
        {
            ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS = "android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS";
        }

        return new Intent(ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS);
    }

    ...
}
```

menu_my_activity.xml:

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MyActivity"
    >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_application_info"
        android:title="@string/action_application_info"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_notification_settings"
        android:title="Notification Settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        />

</menu>
```

MyActivity.java:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_my_activity, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuItem menuItem;
    menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_application_info);
    if (menuItem != null)
    {
        menuItem.setVisible(BuildConfig.DEBUG);
    }
    menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_notification_settings);
    if (menuItem != null)
    {
        menuItem.setVisible(BuildConfig.DEBUG && NotificationListener.supportsNotificationListenerSettings());
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.action_application_info:
            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName())));
            return true;
        case R.id.action_notification_settings:
            startActivity(NotificationListener.getIntentNotificationListenerSettings());
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, I can swear that I am noticing that after about 10-20 toggles or so, it stops working entirely until you reboot. Rinse, repeat.

Comment: I think the problem w/ the NotificationListenerService stopping is due to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/2IegSgtGxyE/iXP3lBCH5SsJ I suspect that the OS is not calling onBind when relaunching a debug session. I added logging to onBind and I see that it is being called very shortly after the old debug session ends, but when the new one starts onBind is never called for the new process.

Comment: I think first paragraph of your answer should be in offcial docs as I had to learn it hard way and lost like 5 hours or so

Answer (score 17):

After installing a app configured properly, you should grant it.

You can find the name of the app at "Settings > Security > Notification access", then be sure the check box is filled. :)

Comment: Check the logs, I frequently see android.os.DeadObjectException from the NotificationManagerService and my callback is not called. Requires uninstall/reinstall of my app to fix.

Answer (score 8):

### update: https://gist.github.com/xinghui/b2ddd8cffe55c4b62f5d8846d5545bf9

```
private void toggleNotificationListenerService() {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(this, com.xinghui.notificationlistenerservicedemo.NotificationListenerServiceImpl.class),
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(this, com.xinghui.notificationlistenerservicedemo.NotificationListenerServiceImpl.class),
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

}
```

[image]

> adb shell dumpsys notification

check which service is living.

> com.android.server.notification.ManagedServices#rebindServices

**toggleNotificationListenerService()** trigger system invoke this method.

Comment: Thanks @hugo this is exactly what i was looking for. Its unfortunate that notification listener service is buggy, but with this hopefully we can force and reload. Atleast I can confirm this will turn off my notification access.

Comment: @Jareddlc update: https://gist.github.com/xinghui/b2ddd8cffe55c4b62f5d8846d5545bf9

Answer (score 4):

I have encountered this bug:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59044

And notifications started coming to my service only after I rebooted my phone.

Comment: even after almost 2-years you posted this, the only way to get the `NotificationManagerService` work is by rebooting the Phone. Strange!!

Comment: @AADProgramming Even after almost another 2 years you posted this comment, I have to do the same reboot

Comment: @Ganesh Even after almost another 1 year, you posted this comment, I have to do the same reboot.

Answer (score 2):

After many hours of researching, I finally found sample code that actually works:

https://github.com/yihongyuelan/NotificationListenerServiceDemo

Answer (score 1):

After debugging multiple times to a device, renaming your NotificationListener class helps fix the problem. It doesn't matter what you rename it to, just changing it to something different from the previous name. I've always had to do this over and over again.

Comment: It's not obvious how this answers the original poster's question - perhaps you can edit your answer to include some example source-code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes deleting build and rebuilding source might be the issue.

I Struggled with it for 3 days, and here is what I have done:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

Changes service name from just class example:

```
<service
          android:name=".NotificationListener"
          android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
          </intent-filter>
      </service>
```

to

```
 <service
          android:name="com.mypackage.example.NotificationListener"
          android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
          </intent-filter>
      </service>
```

Navigate to your root directory > android , then delete build folder, allow your project to rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

NLService will be working all the time as per android docs but in some cases it will be unbind from your specific app and may restarting your phone it will bind again . But in safer side you can have this check whenever your starts ,

```
// check NLsettings
private void checkNLSettings() {
    //check notification access
    if (!NotificationUtils.isNotificationServiceEnabled(this)) {
        //start NLsetting activity
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS");
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ACCESSIBLITYCODE);
        finish();
    }
    //check isNLservice running
    if (!isNLServiceRunning()) {
        enableNotificationListenerService(this);
    }

    Toast.makeText(this, "NLS == " + isNLServiceRunning(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private boolean isNLServiceRunning() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service :
            manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (NLService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * enable notification service.
 *
 * @param context context
 */
public static void enableNotificationListenerService(Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        NotificationListenerService.requestRebind(new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                COMPONENT_NLSERVICE));
    } else {
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                        COMPONENT_NLSERVICE),
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I have just come accross a great little example of this class in action:

http://www.kpbird.com/2013/07/android-notificationlistenerservice.html

One thing I learned from following this example is that the notification service I created starts automatically when permission is granted via the new notification access screen, meaning my application doesn't have to start the service manually.

Comment: That doesn't explain why onNotificationPosted is not called in the first place ! I'm facing the same problem and I'd like to know why it doesn't work before relying on a sample app...

Comment: Agreed, this is plaguing me as well. im also curious if these applications require ongoing notifications to remain active as well.

Comment: There are numerous reasons why your code might not be working that's why studying a working example is good for debugging. Using the example above I'm sure it wouldn't take long to realise what you are doing wrong.