# NotificationListenerService not working - even after giving permission

Tags: android, android-notifications

Below is my code to capture notifications. I dont understand why the **onNotificationPosted** is not getting fired.

I am giving my app Notifications access from Settings > Security and the **onCreate** from MyNotifService is also getting fired, but **onNotificationPosted** is not getting fired.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

From my **MainActivity's onCreate()** function:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyNotifService.class);
this.startService(intent);
```

My Service code that extends **NotificationListenerService**:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MyNotifService extends NotificationListenerService {

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        super.onNotificationPosted(sbn);        
        Log.v("focus", "in onNotificationPosted() of MyNotifService");      
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();       
        Log.v("focus", "in onCreate() of MyNotifService");      
    }
}
```

In the **manifest file**, I have this:

```
<service android:name="com.mavdev.focusoutfacebook.notifications.MyNotifService"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: FOUND FIX: Had to start the phone. Found a link where someone had posted this and details on bug, if i find it again - will post here.

Comment: Start? Do you mean "restart"?

Comment: probably this issue here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62811

Comment: A restart also fixed it for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does seem to be a bit flakey, but this is the actual fix in this case:

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return super.onBind(intent);
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain how this resolves issue? Is it to ensure that service does indeed bind?

Comment: If `onBind()` isn't overridden, `super.conBind()` should be called by itself. How could this override make any difference?

Comment: @SteveBlackwell You are correct, this answer shouldn't make a difference. I think what happened was that I ran into a similar issue as the poster and the issue was that I wasn't explicitly calling the super constructor. I assumed that the poster just excluded this part of the NotificationListenerService from the question and had the same issue but I don't remember

Comment: How will this be a fix. You are just calling super which will be called even if you haven't overridden onBind()

Comment: issue is still exists

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to get it working for the second day, and I succeeded. Try adding these lines at the end of `onStartCommand` method.

And, it hardly plays a role, but try to declare your service after activities in the manifest file.

This comment with sample code was really helpful to me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41521664/10652152