# onNotificationPosted never called

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

I'm trying to implement a feature which would read the notification and it seems that I've a bug in it because the `onNotificationPosted()` of the `NotificationListenerService` is never called. I configured the manifest, modified the security settings properly and even started the service manually but it did nothing. Can it be that testing it in an emulator is not the best way to proceed.

Here is the Notification getter class:

```
/**
* Created by laurentmeyer on 28/02/15.
*/
public class NotificationListener extends NotificationListenerService {
    public NotificationListener(){
        Log.d("Notification", "Created");
    }
@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    Notification mNotification = sbn.getNotification();
    Intent intent = new Intent("Msg");
    Log.d("Notification", "Received");
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d("Notification", "created");
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d("Notification", "destroyed");

}

@Override
public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
}
}
```

(Sorry for the incorrect indentation)

This is my Fragment which should respond to the broadcasts:

```
public class VerificationFragment extends BaseFragment implements SMSReceivedCallbacks {
    public void onNotificationReceived(int code) {
        ed.setText("OK");
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(new Receiver(), new IntentFilter("Msg"));
}
// A bunch of other useless stuff


private class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        onNotificationReceived(0);
    }
}
}
```

The Manifest:

```
<service
        android:name=".NotificationListener"
        android:label="@string/service_name"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
        </intent-filter>
```

To summarise, I've:

```
02-28 11:40:53.236    6585-6585/com.******.laurentmeyer.****** D/Notification﹕ Created
02-28 11:40:53.236    6585-6585/com.******.laurentmeyer.****** D/Notification﹕ created
```

and then nothing. I already looked at all the threads on SO but maybe missing something really simple.

Comment: Have you enabled Notification access for your Service in Settings?

Comment: Yes, of course, that's why I'm a bit lost. Because everything looks correct!

Comment: It works for me actually. I see "Received" in logcat. I've stripped down your code to the bare minimum, i.e. removed all the broadcast and fragment stuff. Not sure what's going on here.

Comment: How do you create the notification you want to listen on? I.e. have you tried creating one on the click of a button from your main activity, just for testing purposes?

Comment: Yes I did, but quite weird that it works. Are you testing on emulator also ?

Comment: No I'm on the phone.

Comment: No i'm not getting it even on phone. Could you please publish what you have on a pastbin/gist please? That'd be very nice :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71968/discussion-between-laurent-meyer-and-ci).

Comment: Sorry, signing off for today. I really only copied your code and deleted a few things that weren't essential to test the logs.

Comment: Yes, of course, see in the chat, I solved it

Comment: Link for the chat is broken. @LaurentMeyer how did you solve it? Please share your solution :)

Comment: Here is my comment with a solution that worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62934667/10652152

Comment: Here is my comment with a solution that worked for me
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62934667/10652152

Answer (score 1):

Enable Notification Access in your settings:

```
if (Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), "enabled_notification_listeners").contains(getApplicationContext().getPackageName())) {
            //Add the code to launch the NotificationService Listener here.
        } else {
            //Launch notification access in the settings...
            getApplicationContext().startActivity(new Intent(
                    "android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS"));
        }
```