# Run method from notification listener when app is in background

Tags: android, notifications, sms

My application is running the method from `notification listener` when the app is running but when the application is in background it does not work.

```
public class NotificationListener extends NotificationListenerService {

  Context context;

  @Override

  public void onCreate() {

    super.onCreate();
    context = getApplicationContext();

    }
@Override

public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

  @Override

  public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    Log.i("Msg","Notification Removed");

    }
}
```

when notification arrives the toast appears when app is running. But i want to **display the toast when app is in background.**

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: You should run some service do this

Comment: Thanks. Please can you guide further. How to implement that

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/q/41425986/4973660