# Why is my NotificationListenerService not working?

Tags: android, service, notifications, listener

I have implemented a NotificationListenerService, yet it is not working. Here is the service:

```
public class NotificationListener extends NotificationListenerService {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.d("MYAPP", "Created");
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    Log.d("MYAPP", "Notification");
}

}
```

I have implemented this in my manifest file:

```
<service android:name="com.rodrigopontes.whatsappbubbles.NotificationListener"
         android:label="Test"
         android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" >
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

This is how I initialize it from my MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    startService(new Intent(this, NotificationListener.class));
}
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Still doesn't work. I get the "Created" message but nothing more. I have also enabled my service to read notifications in the security settings.

Comment: Try to follow [this code example](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/android-notificationlistenerservice-example.html) - you've missed implementing some parts such as creating an instance of the NotificationListener and registering it.

Comment: I think this is the best answer iv seen: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/37081128/1703871](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37081128/1703871)

Answer (score 8):

After many wasted hours I found the answer for this. This is an issue with Android see [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=62811) 
Welcome to Android :)

Comment: Yes, this still seems to be flakey.

Comment: Android is divided into many devices and allows for system customization, so some devices may not work as expected. I don't think you're giving an answer

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. It turned out my app was not allowed to receive notification as it did not have permission. So I enabled the notification permission by following-

```
Intent intent=new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS");
startActivity(intent);
```

Above code opens a notification permission page then select your app and allow.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you haven't provided the Notification Access to your app. Try doing that and it should work

Comment: Right, I enabled the Notification Access  under Special app access settings for the app and it is now able to receive the notification.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the `NotificationListner` was not working after reboot. I am working with android 10 i have find out solution on this.

```
 @Override
public void onListenerConnected() {
    super.onListenerConnected();
    Log.i("tag","Listner conneted");
    tryReconnectService();
}


 public void tryReconnectService() {
    toggleNotificationListenerService();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        ComponentName componentName =
                new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), Whatsapp_recorder.class);

        //It say to Notification Manager RE-BIND your service to listen notifications again inmediatelly!
        requestRebind(componentName);
    }
}


  private void toggleNotificationListenerService() {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(this, Whatsapp_recorder.class),
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(this, Whatsapp_recorder.class),
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

Try this it is working for me

Answer (score 1):

Some comments here mention other solutions, some of which led me to this:

https://gist.github.com/xinghui/b2ddd8cffe55c4b62f5d8846d5545bf9

The problem is, if I understand it correctly, that the service process is running, but is completely disconnected from, well, anything.

The gist is a service class which checks if your NotificationListenerService process is actually running and "connected" to whatever takes care of notifications inside the OS and if it isn't, restarts it (or rather enables the component, as starting it the usual way is exactly what's broken).

I've tried this solution on Android 7.1.1, where I was unable to use the NotificationListenerService, and it worked.