# How to effectively kill Android Notification Manager / NotificationListenerService?

Tags: android, notifications, android-service, android-notifications

In our app we catch notifications thrown by other apps. Sometimes the app stops to receive any more notifications. But we cannot reproduce this behavior. Do you know how to force a `NotifactionListenerService` crash?

In our app we have a service that extends from `NotifcationListenerService`. Just calling `stopSelf()` does not stop the service. So I tought about two solutions to reproduce the behavior:

1. Force our Service that extends from `NotifcationListenerService` to stop
2. Force the Android internal notification service to stop

**Trying Solution 1:** As I told you if I want to stop our service with `stopSelf()` it does not really stop. If I list all the processes(with `pstree`) on my device when our app is running I can see alls subprocesses/threads created by our app. If I kill some of these with `kill` command, the app's task switches to the background but our Notifcation Service is still running and receiving notifications.

**Trying Solution 2:** By running `ps` I found ad `notification-sq`process running, forked from Androids `system_server`. If i kill this process with `kill` command then my Android device restarts automatically.

Both ideas don't work. So do you maybe know how to make the Notifaction Service crash?

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: You can get the Notification Listener Service crash by starting app in debug mode. Recreating the service is possible on some crashes. Have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47964645/2039740