# How to prevent NotificationListener from getting disconnected?

Tags: android-studio, notification-listener

I made an app with a Notification Listener which should observe every notification. But after a certain time the Listener is destroyed or disconnected. What can I do to prevent this?

I tried calling the onConnected method but it doesn't work.

I want the Listener to stay always active.

Answer (score 0):

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(this,com.xinghui.notificationlistenerservicedemo.NotificationListenerServiceImpl.class),           PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(this,com.xinghui.notificationlistenerservicedemo.NotificationListenerServiceImpl.class),        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

that worked for me. check this out:[Cannot get the NotificationListenerService class to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911883/cannot-get-the-notificationlistenerservice-class-to-work)
thx to Hugo